# Problems with positioning and z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have the menu overlap content, but as of now it moves the content box away.

I've already tried the `position: relative` trick, but the problem doesn't seem to go away. The solution is probably something really obvious, but I need help finding it.

**EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add, the box will also be resizable() so I'm trying to avoid absolute positioning.**
**EDIT2: nevermind, `right:5px` fixes that problem**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CcVnL/6/)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="menubox">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Option 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Option 2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>content goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: LightGray;
    border: 1px solid DarkGray;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: lightblue;
}
.icon {
    float: right;
    background: red;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.menubox {
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    width: 150px;
}
.content {
    width: 180px;
    height: 165px;
    margin: 0px 10px 47px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    background:DarkGray;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    margin:none;
    padding:none;
}
```

JS/jQuery

```
$('.icon').mouseover(function () {
    $(".menu").show();
}); //toggle menu on hover
$(".menu").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position: absolute`?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/CcVnL/16/)

```
.menubox {
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    width: 150px;
    top: 25px;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: LightGray;
    border: 1px solid DarkGray;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
```

**Edit**: better position

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add, the box will also be `resizable()` so I'm trying to avoid absolute positioning

Comment: if you resize the box in the fiddle the menu will still stick to the right, so it should be fine [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/CcVnL/17/). If you provide a example of the box being `resizable()` it may help?

Answer (score 1):

The yellow menubox needs to be positioned absolutely so it does not interfere with the flow of the document (take up space).

Give it a `position:absolute;`

Furthermore, the .box element needs to have a `position:relative` so the menu is positioned relative to that box.

Updated your fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/CcVnL/11/

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link i have updated your code.
"jsfiddle.net/CcVnL/9/"